# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

Tags: java, servlets

I want to try a simple program but getting following error. I am using Eclipse Kelper and Tomcat 7.0. 
Tried a lot of things, but nothing is working for me.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

There is source code:

- web.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Processes application requests -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- servlet-context.xml:

  ```
  ?
  ```

Could somebody explain what is the problem?

Comment: Don't you miss `servlet-context.xml` in the question?

Comment: Which JDK are you using? Which version of Spring?

Answer (score 5):

Try this configuration  or rename your config accordingly :
I prefer to name the servlet as 'dispatcher' and it's context file as dispatcher-servlet.xml. It worked fine for me.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet.init() errors mainly occur due to mismatching of versions of the Jar files of your spring MVC, Check out all your libraries by right click on the project>properties>build path, and remove any mismatched jar release.

Also delete the jar library from your lib folder.
Build the project again and the run it.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:
servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-1.1"> 
  <dep:environment xmlns:dep="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.1">
    <dep:moduleId>
      <dep:groupId>org.apache.geronimo.samples.jws</dep:groupId>
      <dep:artifactId>Calculator</dep:artifactId> 
      <dep:version>1.0</dep:version> 
      <dep:type>car</dep:type>
    </dep:moduleId>
    <dep:dependencies>
    </dep:dependencies>
  </dep:environment>
  <context-root>/jaxws-calculator-1.0</context-root>
  <service-ref> 
    <service-ref-name>services/Calculator</service-ref-name>
    <port> 
      <port-name>CalculatorPort</port-name>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host> 
      <port>8080</port> 
      <uri>/jaxws-calculator/calculator</uri> 
    </port>
  </service-ref>
</web-app>
```