# Servlet.init() for servlet com.imajinair.santapp.SantappApplication threw exception

Tags: java, apache-tomee

i am new in tomee and java web application. i got this error while run my application.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet com.imajinair.santapp.SantappApplication threw exception
type Exception report
message Servlet.init() for servlet com.imajinair.santapp.SantappApplication threw exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.imajinair.santapp.SantappApplication threw exception
org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i'm using Netbeans, use drop rwa tomee 1.7.2

edit post:
thanks to  Prince Mani Gupta, for the suggestion.
now i have the problem, my entity manager is null.
this is my code:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "imajinair.com_Santapp_war_1.0-BetaPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701091/http-status-500-servlet-init-for-servlet-appservlet-threw-exception

Comment: thanks it works!. but now my entity manager is null. please see my edit post to see my code @PrinceManiGupta